# Django Rest Framework UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Model available:**

```
photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Фото', upload_to='images/human/%Y/%m/%d/', 
default='default/user.png', blank=True)
    photo_200 = ImageSpecField(
        source='photo',
        processors=[ResizeToFill(200, 200)],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 80},
    )
    photo_272 = ImageSpecField(
        source='photo',
        processors=[ResizeToFill(272, 250)],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 80},
    )
```

**serializer:**

```
class HumanListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = (
            'name',
            'surname',
            'middle_name',
            'description',
            'photo_272',
            'slug'
        )
```

I get an error on `photo_272` `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

with picture `photo` everything is in order, since it is not used django rest framework

Comment: 1) Speculative guess: you are using wrong encoding, fixing the encoding should solve the problem. At least for me it was the case. 2) You are not showing the part of your code where the decoding takes place, this is the part where the error occurs.

Comment: Please add more info about the error, like, the complete error traceback, method to reproduce the error etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the django rest framework doesn't know how to serialize ImageSpecField properly since it's not a standard django model field. So you need to add a custom method to the serializer

```
class HumanListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo_272 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = (
            'name',
            'surname',
            'middle_name',
            'description',
            'photo_272',
            'slug'
        )
    
    def get_photo_272(self, record: Human):
        return record.photo_272.url
```